# Getting a compile link error in the following program

Tags: c++, header, linker

I am getting an error and I have absolutely no idea why.. I have already searched this site and cannot find anything...

My error is: `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall campaign::~campaign(void)" (??1campaign@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall sale::sale(int,int,int,class agent,class campaign)"

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h";
#include <iostream>
#include "campaign.h";

//constructor
campaign::campaign()
{
    campaign_name = "Campaign Undefined";
    campaign_id = -1;
    campaign_data_type = 0;
    campaign_region_type = 0;
}

/////////////////////////////
//Accessor Functions      //
///////////////////////////

std::string campaign::getName()
{
    return campaign_name;
}

int campaign::getCampID()
{
    return campaign_id;
}

int campaign::getDataType()
{
    return campaign_data_type;
}

int campaign::getRegionType()
{
    return campaign_region_type;
}

/////////////////////////////
//Mutator Functions       //
///////////////////////////

void campaign::setName(std::string newName)
{
    campaign_name = newName;
}

void campaign::setCampID(int newCampID)
{
    campaign_id = newCampID;
}

void campaign::setDataType(int newDType)
{
    campaign_data_type = newDType;
}

void campaign::setRegionType(int newRType)
{
    campaign_region_type = newRType;
}
```

Sorry for the super long  post, If somebody here has about 15 minutes and has nothing better to do, I would appreciate it if you could sift through my code and give me a clue as to what i am doing wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: The linker clearly states `unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall campaign::~campaign(void)"`, that should give you a clue !

Comment: you declare ~campaign destructor but you don't define it anywhere

Comment: I don't really understand what that means to be honest, sorry for being really dumb :( I'm new to this whole c++ stuff - Mind giving me another hint?

Comment: in campaign header you declare a destructor (~campaign) but you don't define it in the implementation. If you don't want to write a destructor then remove its declaration from header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define your destructor for `campaign`. Put this in your implementation file for it:

```
campaign::~campaign()
{

}
```

If you want your class to use the default destructor, you can remove `~campaign(void);` from your header file and then do you do not need to define it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't implement `campain::~campain()`. Since you declared it in header file you should provide definition. In your case destructor is not required and the default one provided by compiler will suffice. So remove the declaration from header file.

Comment: Hah, i feel dumb now... Thanks for helping !:)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the `campaign` destructor, but have not defined it anywhere:

```
class campaign
{
    public:
        campaign();
        ~campaign(); // you need a definition for this
```

You need to either provide a definition for it (an implementation) or, if you don't need the destructor to do anything special, remove the declaration and let the compiler provide a destructor automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Nbr44 already commented, you didn't define your `campaign::~campaign` destructor. You declared it in the header file but you didn't supply a definition

Answer (score 0):

You don't implement your campaign destructor.
If it's trivial don't declare it